# How to fix a headerView of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sections

I have a UITableView with two sections. The first section could be have 16 rows, and the second section could be have 9 rows. I have two custom viewHeaders for the sections with a title and custom bakground.

Could be possible set and keep the header sections in a determined position like this picture? An then show only a few of rows and do scroll to show this but keep the section header on screen middle?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use 2 `UITableView` to achieve it?

Comment: Using two UitableView seems the best idea to achieve this

Comment: Very custom task, i think u must create UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewLayout with stick headers with specific behaviour. Or Rly just use two tables if you have static row counts.

Comment: 2 tableview if you don't want to scroll 2nd section header... else what you are asking is default behavior of tableview...

Comment: I was trying do it with only one UITableview, but with your comments I understand that it is only possible to do it with two UITableViews. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add two tableViews in a single tableViewController.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (tableView == myTableView1) {
   // cell for tableView 1
} else {
   // cell for tableView 2 
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (tableView == myTableView1) {
   //return header section 0 
} else {
  // return header section 1

}
```

set all delegate method like this.

how to fix height?

in `viewDidAppear` set

```
[tableView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
[tableView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
```

Comment: I'm trying this code, but never execute the if condition for mi second tableView. I have added the UITableViews to the same view in .xib and use registerNib: and reuseIdentifier custom .xib cells. I added the delegate and dataSource. What could be the problem? Thanks